# Aframe inside StencilJS web component

Tags: npm, web-component, aframe, stenciljs

sorry for my dummy question.

I would like to create some web components using a-frame.
For example:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <title>Stencil Component Starter</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/build/iseeve3d.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="/build/iseeve3d.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <a-scene>
    <my-component />
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Into the components, I have:

```
@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return (
    <Host>
        <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
        <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
        <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </Host>);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?
I've also tried to include aframe npm library, but it seems impossible to use components like ,  using npm library.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: "A-Frame is based on top of HTML and the DOM using a polyfill for Custom Elements."  (from https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/html-and-primitives.html)... maybe it interferes with Stencil? Or maybe you just need to wrap it all in `<a-scene></a-scene>`?

Comment: Beacause my idea is to create a component, for example, to group a big number of boxes with a backend call to obtain the number of boxes, or change the environment dynamically or load music, video and so on.
I don't know if it is the best approach, because we can use a-frame with javascript, but maybe this approach is impossible to reach out (I've not too experiences with these libraries). Thank you for your time

Comment: Any luck with this?